# repeat ggplot using different data without typing out the whole code

Tags: r, ggplot2

Is a way to re-plot something but using a subsetted dataset without writing the entire code out again?

maybe something like last_plot() but allow one to specific the data.frame to use?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question - I can't tell _exactly_ what you're trying to do, or why.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the `%+%` operator:

```
##Two data sets:
R> dd = data.frame(x = runif(10), y=runif(10))
R> dd_new = data.frame(x = runif(10), y=runif(10))

R> g = ggplot(dd, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() 
R> g
R> g %+% dd_new
```

Comment: Maybe obvious, but worth pointing out that after using the `%+%` operator you can continue to use the `+` operator as well: `g %+% dd_new + labs(title="Best Graph")`

Comment: Not necessarily obvious! One handy trick is adding a call to `ggsave()` to output your new plot to file.

Answer (score 6):

Although I feel that Csgillespie's answer is complete. I'd like to add a secondary method that I personally use quite frequently, but rarely see out in the wild. It's great for applying corporate/personal themes and avoiding retyping one's work.

You can save ggplot2 elements as a list, just as though you were writing them with `... + ... +`

```
default.point <- list(geom_point(), 
coord_flip(),
theme(
axis.text.x=element_text(size=12
)))

ggplot(diamonds,aes(carat, price, colour=cut)) + default.point
```